# D3.js - first value of array gets lost

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a very basic example of D3.js and I am quite confused.

```js
const arr = [20, 30, 50]

const paragraphs = d3.select("body")
  .data(arr)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

I expected the enter method to create a placeholder for every element in the array. However the first elements seems to get lost and I don´t understand why. What is the reason for this behaviour and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `data(arr)` on a selection of nodes (that don't exist yet). The data is then bound to this placeholder selection.

```js
const arr = [20, 30, 50]

const paragraphs = d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
  .data(arr)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Agreed. Check out this tutorial https://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/binding-data